# Push elements in an Array into array using PHP

Tags: php

Im a new bie to PHP..

I'm able to push the elements into an Array using array_push. It gives the output like this..

```
array(0) { } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "For all your PC requirements" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(28) "For all your PC requirements" [1]=> string(10) "Welcome to" }
```

My code is

```
if($msgIdFound == 1){
$parts = explode('msgid ', $line_of_text);
$fp = fopen("/home/bigc/Documents/msgids.csv","w"); 

    array_push($msgIds,$m[1]);                  

$counter++;
var_dump($msgIds);
fputcsv($fp, $msgIds);
fclose($fp);
}
```

But, what I want the array looks like this.

array(array('For all your PC requirements'),
array('Welcome to'))

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are pushing a *string* to it. How to you want to be an *array*? Push an array intead.

Answer (score 3):

You can put

```
msgIds[] = array($m[1]);
```

instead of array_push(...)

Comment: This is the better answer. no reason to use array_push here. msgIds[] runs faster.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
array_push($msgIds,$m[1]);
```

with

```
if (!empty($m[1])) { // avoid empty stuff...
    array_push($msgIds, array($m[1]));
}
```

this should result in:

```
array(2)(
    [0] => 
    array(1){
        [0] => 
        string(28) "For all your PC requirements"
    }
    [0] => 
    array(1){
        [0] => 
        string(10) "Welcome to"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a string when you should push an array:

```
if($msgIdFound == 1){
  $parts = explode('msgid ', $line_of_text);
  $fp = fopen("/home/bigc/Documents/msgids.csv","w"); 

  array_push($msgIds, array($m[1])); // you need to push an array             

  $counter++;
  var_dump($msgIds);
  fputcsv($fp, $msgIds);
  fclose($fp);
}
```